# Help needed for JPA/hibernate - problems with creating entity classes

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I started creating JPA/hibernate mappings for a legacy database based on Oracle. At one (early...) point I have a many-to-many relation between to tables (FOO, BAR, join table with extra fields: FOO_BAR). So I defined three entities, created an embeddable Id class for the join table, strictly following some examples from a good (?!) book.

I can select a Foo but whenever I try to read the related Bars from the result set, I get wither an "SQLException: No data found" or a "SQLException: General error (S1000)". I can switch between the two by just changing some java types of the entity beans...

The log contains the following line n case of the "No data found" error:

```
INFO org.hibernate.type.LongType - could not read column value from result set: Foo1_2_; No data found
```

The columns FOO_ID and BAR_ID are defined as `NUMBER(22)`. I tried `Long` types first, this resulted in "No data found", `Double` led to "General error". Then I read somewhere that the standard mapping for `NUMBER` is `BigDecimal` (-> "General Error"), I tried `BigInteger` instead (-> "No data found").

I'm lost.

When I take the sql statement from the logs and use it with "native" jdbc, ... it works fine.

```
PreparedStatement prep = con.prepareStatement(sqlQueryFromHibernateLogs);
prep.setBigDecimal(1, new  BigDecimal(1));
ResultSet rs = prep.executeeQuery();  // result set has the correct values...
```

Any help, suggestions, pointers to helpful resources are highly appreciated. Oh, one final thing to mention: I'm 'forced' to use the JdbcOdbc bridge. It's really a legacy system...

---

My select statement goes like this:

```
List<Foo> foos = em.createQuery("select f from Foo f order by f.name").getResultList();
```

---

**Edit**

Versions - I'm bound to the hibernate libraries that are shipped with the play framework (1.0.3.2). The hibernate3.jar has no useful version information (nothing in Manifest, `Version#getVersionString()` says `[WORKING]`), the other hibernatexxx jars report as 3.1.0.GA (validator) or 3.4.0.GA (entitymanager).

---

**Edit 2**

I've reduced the classes to the absolute minimum with the errors still present. This is what I did:

*Foo.java*

```
@Entitiy @Table(name="FOO")
public class Foo {
  @Id @Column(name="FOO_ID")
  private BigInteger fooId;

  Foo(){}

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="foo")
  private Set<FooBar> fooBars = new HashSet<FooBar>();
}
```

*Bar.java*

```
@Entitiy @Table(name="BAR")
public class Bar {
  @Id @Column(name="BAR_ID")
  private BigInteger fooId;

  Bar(){}

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="bar")
  private Set<FooBar> fooBars = new HashSet<FooBar>();
}
```

*FooBar.java*

```
@Entitiy @Table(name="FOOBAR")
public class FooBar {

  @Embeddable
  public static class Id implements Serializable {
    @Column(name="FOO_ID")
    private BigInteger fooId;
    @Column(name="BAR_ID")
    private BigInteger barId;

    Id() {}

    // implementations of hashcode and equals

  }

  @Embedded
  private Id id = new Id();

  @ManytoOne @JoinColumn(name = "FOO_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
  private Foo foo;

  @ManytoOne @JoinColumn(name = "BAR_ID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
  private Bar bar;

  FooBar(){}
}
```

`FOO_ID` and `BAR_ID` are defined as `NUMBER(22)` on the the Oracle database. The above example leads to the "No data found" error, replacing `BigInteger` with `Long` results in the "General Error". And sending the very same SQL expression over the bridge gives a correct result set...

Comment: *I'm 'forced' to use the JdbcOdbc bridge* Oh my... In case this could be relevant, what dialect are you using? What version of Hibernate?

Comment: @Pascal - the dialect is `Oracle10gDialect`, hibernate is 3-dot-something (have to look it up). But, as I said, native jdbc (same statement) works with the bridge...

Comment: Yes, I got that. But Hibernate is involved in the issue, IMO :)

Comment: If possible, let us know which version you use

Comment: @Arthur - edited the question and added all available version information (which is not too much...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution or - at least - found out, that the approach can't work with the given tools (hibernate, JdbcOdbc bridge):

Some more googeling finally sent me to [this (german) page](http://forum.fachinformatiker.de/java/81925-resultset-abfrage-no-data-found.html), where someone had a similiar problem: a `No data found` SQLException while working with the bridge. Someone else answered, that the code is correct but it is a problem with the JdbcOdbc bridge which does not support reading a result set more than once. I can't clarify, if I have the same problem here, but I'm pretty sure that it is this or a similiar case and the problem is related to using the bridge with hibernate/JPA.

For my very special case: I solved the problem by ignoring it after ... finally finding out that I **can** use the oracle oci driver. (*sigh*)

Thanks to everyone who tried to follow my posting and thought about a solution!

Comment: Before Up voting, would be possible you mark any BigInteger @Column as @Column(presicion=22) and see what happens. Although precision is used for BigDecimal values (http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Column.html#precision%28%29) It works when using a BigInteger (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916838)